# Calculating distance between two locations in android while driving

Tags: android, distance, google-directions-api

I have developed an app like uber but I am facing issue in calculating correct fare due to incorrect distance from pick up location to the location where trip completed.
What I have done and doing:

**1st approach**

I was getting distance between between current location of the driver(save location when trip started) and end location(where trip completed)
like this.

```
distanceInMeters = locationChanged.getmCurrentlocation().distanceTo(loc_pick_up);
```

but problem with this code is. if passenger pick up location(where trip started) and drop off location(where trip completed) is same distance is zero.

**2nd Approach**

Now I am calling a method every minute. which when executed first time. calculate distance between pickup location(from where trip started) and current location(location after  1 minute) and save difference in a variable. and than current location becomes pickup location and when method is executed again. it calculates distance between pickuplocation and current location (between location before and after 1 minutes) and add the result in already saved distance.

```
private void locationDistanceHandler() {

    handlerLocation = new Handler();
    runnableCode = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Location loc_pick_up = new Location("");
            if (!pick_up_value_used) {
                loc_pick_up.setLatitude(pickUpLatLng.latitude);
                loc_pick_up.setLongitude(pickUpLatLng.longitude);
                locationChanged.setmPickUpLocation(locationChanged.getmCurrentlocation());
                pick_up_value_used = true;
            } else {
                loc_pick_up.setLatitude(locationChanged.getmPickUpLocation().getLatitude());
                loc_pick_up.setLongitude(locationChanged.getmPickUpLocation().getLongitude());
            }
            Log.d(Constants.LOG, "handle location called:" + distanceInMeters);
            distanceInMeters = distanceInMeters + locationChanged.getmCurrentlocation().distanceTo(loc_pick_up);
            handlerLocation.postDelayed(this, 60000);
        }
    };
    handlerLocation.postDelayed(runnableCode, 60000);
}
```

But this is not accurate. today I travelled 20 km from office to home in 18 minutes. but this method calculated distance 6.8km.

Please suggest me a better way of doing this or any working source code example. so I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] results=new float[5];
                loc_pick_up.distanceBetween(startLatitude,startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude,results);
                String calculatedDistance=results[0];
                System.out.println("Distance between point A and point B are: " + calulcatedDistance);
```

Comment: are you sure ? i am using distanceTo. what is difference between these two ?

Comment: From what I see distanceTo is used to calculate the distance from your current position to a destination. DistanceBetween is used for distance between location A and location B. But you can also put the current location as the starting, I usually have a tough time with distanceTo with accuracy for some reason.